# How to solve multiple class inheritance without duplicating code in my case?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

My concrete classes can be one of the type permutations shown below. But, since I cannot inherit from two classes (case 4 and 5) I had to convert one of them to interface which introduce code duplication shown in **FIX** section below. I know someone will say "use composition", but I don't see how to change the design to take this into account.

Type permutations:

1. `ControllerSimulator`
2. `MovingControllerSimulator`
3. `RegistersControllerSimulator`
4. `ControllerSimulator` + `RegistersControllerSimulator`
5. `MovingControllerSimulator` + `RegistersControllerSimulator`

**CODE**

```
public abstract class ControllerSimulator
{
   protected virtual void OnTurningOn() { }
   public void TurnOn()
   { 
     ...
   }
   
   protected virtual void OnTurningOff() { }
   public void TurnOff()
   { 
     ...
   }

   // more base methods
   ...
}

public abstract class MovingControllerSimulator : ControllerSimulator
{
   public virtual void Disable() { }

   public void SetMotionDuration(TimeSpan duration)
   {
       _motionDuration = duration;
   }

    protected void OnMoveStarted()
    {
       MoveStarted?.Invoke();
    }

    // more base methods
    ...
}

public abstract class RegistersControllerSimulator : ControllerSimulator
{
   protected Dictionary<string, object> Registers;
   
   protected abstract void OnRegisterChanged(string regName, object regVal); 
   public void UpdateRegister(string regName, object regVal)
   {
      Registers[regName] = regVal;
      OnRegisterChanged(...);
   }

   // more base methods
   ...
}
```

**FIX**

Since I cannot inherit from two classes I decided to convert `RegistersControllerSimulator` to an interface and create `RegistersMovingControllerSimulator` and `RegistersNonMovingControllerSimulator`. But, this requires code duplication which I potentially can solve by moving it to utils.

**interface**

```
interface IRegistersControllerSimulator
{
   void UpdateRegister(string regName, object regVal);
}

public abstract class RegistersMovingControllerSimulator : MovingControllerSimulator, IRegistersControllerSimulator
{
   protected Dictionary<string, object> Registers;
   
   protected abstract void OnRegisterChanged(string regName, object regVal); 
   public void UpdateRegister(string regName, object regVal)
   {
      Registers[regName] = regVal;
      OnRegisterChanged(...);
   }
}    

public abstract class RegistersNonMovingControllerSimulator : ControllerSimulator, IRegistersControllerSimulator
{
   protected Dictionary<string, object> Registers;
   
   protected abstract void OnRegisterChanged(string regName, object regVal); 
   public void UpdateRegister(string regName, object regVal)
   {
      Registers[regName] = regVal;
      OnRegisterChanged(...);
   }
}
```

**Concrete classes**

```
public class Concrete_Registers_Moving_Controller : RegistersMovingControllerSimulator
{
    protected override void OnRegisterChanged(string regName, object regVal)
    {
        if (regName == "Move")
        {
           // imitate Move
           OnMoveStarted();
           // I know `.Wait()` is bad here, but it's just an example
           Task.Delay(_motionDuration).Wait();
        }
    }

    public Task StartMoveAsync2()
    {
         ...
         OnMoveStarted();
         return Task.Delay(_motionDuration);
    }
}

public class Concrete_Registers_NonMoving_Controller : RegistersNonMovingControllerSimulator
{
   protected override void OnRegisterChanged(string regName, object regVal)
    {
        if (regName == "Move2")
        {
           ...
           // imitate Move
           OnMoveStarted();
           // I know `.Wait()` is bad here, but it's just an example
           Task.Delay(_motionDuration).Wait();
        }
    }
}

public class Concrete_NonRegisters_Moving_Controller : MovingControllerSimulator
{
    public Task StartMoveAsync()
    {
         OnMoveStarted();
         return Task.Delay(_motionDuration);
    }
}

public class Concrete_NonRegisters_NonMoving_Controller : ControllerSimulator
{
}
```

**USAGE**

```
var controllerRegMove = new Concrete_Registers_Moving_Controller();
controllerRegMove.UpdateRegister(...);
controllerRegMove.SetMotionDuration(...);
controllerRegMove.StartMoveAsync2();

var controllerRegNonMove = new Concrete_Registers_NonMoving_Controller();
controllerRegNonMove.UpdateRegister(...);
controllerRegNonMove.SomeNonMoveMethod(...);

var controllerNonRegMove = new Concrete_NonRegisters_Moving_Controller();
controllerNonRegMove.SetMotionDuration(...);
controllerNonRegMove.StartMoveAsync();

var controllerNonRegNonMove = new Concrete_NonRegisters_NonMoving_Controller();
controllerNonRegNonMove.SomeNonMoveMethod2(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know someone will say "use composition"

Yes, use composition.

[What you can do with inheritance you can also do with composition](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/02/19/abstract-class-isomorphism). The reverse isn't true, because you can compose objects with multiple capabilities, but you can't inherit from more than one base class.

So how would you go about it in this case?

It's not entirely clear to me how the various classes in the OP hierarchy are supposed to work together, but since it sounds as though you have two axes of variability, you'll need two services:

```
public interface IMovingThingy
{
    // ...
}

public interface IRegistersThingy
{
    // ...
}
```

Here I've used Dan North's *Thingy* naming convention for placeholder names until something better comes to mind.

Now inject those into the Controller class:

```
public sealed class ControllerSimulator
{
    private readonly IMovingThingy moving;
    private readonly IRegistersThingy registers;

    public ControllerSimulator(IMovingThingy moving, IRegistersThingy registers)
    {
        this.moving = moving;
        this.registers = registers;
    }

    public void TurnOn()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void TurnOff()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // More methods...
}
```

You can now vary movement and registers independently.

If you want to reuse methods from one object in another object, you can define the interface methods so that the other classes pass themselves as arguments, but be careful with that, since it indicates two-way coupling that will make it more difficult to maintain the code. There's usually a better alternative to such designs.

Comment: But, not all controllers are Moving contollers, for example `public class Concrete_Registers_NonMoving_Controller` in my example. Your design requires me to pass `IMovingThingy`, which I assume you meant it would be `MovingControllerSimulator`. The same is true that not all controllers `RegistersController`. I also updated the code to show how the "moving" controllers use functionality from the base `MovingControllerSimulator` class.

Comment: @theateist If you don't want the _moving_ capability, pass in a [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) implementation of the interface.

Comment: I don't think this approach solves this. I added the usage in my post. Can you take a look and let me know how your suggestion allows me to use it like that? I'm willing to change the usage if you see other way.

Comment: @theateist AFAICT all methods in the proposed API have `void` returns, so they can *trivially* have Null Object implementations. In that light, then, why wouldn't it work?

Comment: I added **USAGE** section in my post. Can you take a look and explain how do I call those methods with your approach? Or, are you saying I should add `UpdateRegister`, `StartMoveAsync`, `SetMotionDuration`, `SomeNonMoveMethod`, `SomeNonMoveMethod2` and all other methods into single `ControllerSimulator` class and just have those methods to call corresponding methods from `IMovingThingy` and `IRegistersThingy `?

Comment: @theateist You could do that, or you could have several concrete classes that take the same kinds of dependencies.

Comment: I don't like the first approach since `ControllerSimulator` will have methods that some controllers will never use. For example, if a controller is not of type `IRegistersControllerSimulator`, then `UpdateReigster` will never be used. I prefer for a class to have only methods that are relevent to it. I don't understand your second approach. It seems with your approach the classes won't have common interface (or abstarct class) and thus I won't be able to add controllers to a collection of `IRegistersControllerSimulator` or `MovingControllerSimulator` controllers for example.

Comment: @theateist Even if you have several concrete classes they can still implement a common interface, or inherit from a base class, if that's what you need.

Comment: but using base class brings me back to my original question. Could you please post an example that allows to use as shown in **USAGE** section?

Comment: @theateist I've noticed that you've reacted with some incredulity to someone else's close vote, but I have to concur insofar as the details of what you need aren't at all clear. It's not that I don't want to help (as this thread should, I hope, amply demonstrate), but I can't really get more specific until you edit the post to supply a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your usage shows that having the behaviors (registering and moving) depends on concrete types. So you can't define an actual interface in the usage to represent the required concrete type. That's the real problem. If your client knows what interface it needs, you can decide on creation with a factory.

Comment: I suggest you refactor the usage part to use interfaces instead of concrete types.